# How to delete the contents of temp folder in remote machine through command

Tags: windows, wmic

I have a requirement where i need to delete the contents of the temp folder on number of remote windows machines.
i tried below wmic command to delete

**WMIC /node:**.**.**.** /user:xxxx /password:xxxx path cim_datafile WHERE "path='%Winddir%\temp*.tmp' AND  Extension ='tmp'" delete**

But it throws an error saying

ERROR:
Description = The RPC server is unavailable.

Please suggest me a way to delete temp folder contents on remote machine.

Answer (score 1):

Most simple way - if you're not strictly forced to use WMI, you can do that with psexec:

```
PsExec.exe \\<computer> cmd /c "rmdir /s /q %windir%\temp\"
```

or, if you're not logged into domain admin or global workstations admin account -

```
PsExec.exe -u <user> -p <password> \\<computer> cmd /c "rmdir /s /q %windir%\temp\"
```

If should not completely delete the folder since Windows keeps some files open and locked inside it, but anything not read-only or locked would be deleted, both files and folders.

Then, to do this with a list of computers, just use a cmd file like this (list.txt contains just computer names/ips, without \:

```
for /F %%s in (list.txt) do (
    echo %%s
    start "" /min PsExec.exe \\%%s cmd /c "rmdir /s /q %windir%\temp\"
)
```

Start command makes all psexec processes run in parallel and minimized so you don't have to wait for each computer to finish before starting another

psexec.exe is a part of sysinternals package from M. Russinovich, I'd like to leave a direct link but don't know if it's permitted or not.
I think it should be able to connect to remote pcs if you have access to file shares and remote computer management (and admin rights of course)